# Custom Delegate Method Not being Called in other custom class with its custom delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have two classes with custom delegates. First class has a required method that is called correctly in view controllers. When I try to use delegate method from first class in the second class that has its own delegate, nothing happens. I see that delegate method was never called. Here are the class interface declarations for these two classes:
***Class A:***

```
@class ServerCommunication;
@protocol ServerCommunicationDelegate;

@interface ServerCommunication : NSObject


@property (weak, nonatomic) id <ServerCommunicationDelegate> delegate;

-(void)requestPageXMLForURLString:(NSString *)stringURL;
-(void)getPreviewBlastsListXMLFromBlastsListItems:(NSString *)blastsIdsString;

@end

@protocol ServerCommunicationDelegate <NSObject>

@required

- (void)didFinishUIXMLRequestWithSuccess:(NSString *)responseXMLString;
@end
```

***Class B:***

```
@class AnnotationsListViews;
@protocol AnnotationsListViewsDelegate;

@interface AnnotationsListViews : NSObject<ServerCommunicationDelegate>
{
GDataXMLDocument *listViewXML;
}

 @property (weak, nonatomic) id <AnnotationsListViewsDelegate> delegate;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *blastsIds;

 - (id)initWithBlastsIds:(NSString *)blastsIdsString;
 -(void)getPreviewBlastsListXMLFromBlastsListItems:(NSString *)blastsIdsString;

 @end
 @protocol AnnotationsListViewsDelegate <NSObject>

 @required
 -(void)selectedAnnotationsListTitleText:(NSString *)listTitle;
 -(void)annotationsListViewsGeneratedWithViewsArray:(NSArray *)requestedBlastsListItemsViews;
```

@end
Here is the method in Class B .m file that calls first class'delegate method:

```
-(void)getXML:(NSString *)blastsIdsString{
   ServerCommunication *connectionToServer=[[ServerCommunication alloc] init];
   connectionToServer.delegate=self;
   [connectionToServer getPreviewBlastsListXMLFromBlastsListItems:blastsIdsString];
}
```

Last line of the code works fine, calls "getPreviewBlastsListXMLFromBlastsListItems" from first class. Executes every line of code in second class. But follow delegate method does not get called.
***Delegate to be called:***

```
#pragma mark - ServerCommunicationDelegate
- (void)didFinishUIXMLRequestWithSuccess:(NSString *)responseXMLString{
    NSLog(@"sasasassasasasasasasaa");
}
```

***Same calling method and delegate method, I have been using in all of my view controller classes and they work fine.*** In this case I see that even **NSLog** does not prints anything. I think that there is some separate to handle calling delegate methods in a class inherited from NSObject class. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `ServerCommunication *connectionToServer` to an `@property`, like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ServerCommunication *connectionToServer;
```

and change `getXML:` method to

```
-(void)getXML:(NSString *)blastsIdsString{
   self.connectionToServer=[[ServerCommunication alloc] init];
   self.connectionToServer.delegate=self;
   [self.connectionToServer getPreviewBlastsListXMLFromBlastsListItems:blastsIdsString];
}
```

Also make the instance of class B ie. `AnnotationsListViews` to an `@property`.

Comment: Still nothing happens. I clearly mentioned above that same code is used in all other view controllers and it works fine.....

Comment: How u used the instance of `Class B`?

Comment: AnnotationsListViews *annotsView=[[AnnotationsListViews alloc] init];
    annotsView.delegate=self;
    [annotsView getXML:allBlastsIDsString];

Comment: Make `AnnotationsListViews *annotsView` also an `@property` and check

Comment: Doing this worked. But I don't understand, why the same code worked in other view controller classes without the need of making property?

Comment: Here you have two instances, one inside another. So if one of them releases the delegate method will not get fired.

Answer (score 1):

Does `connectionToServer` release itself after `getXML:` method called. So nothing will call the delegate. Check if `connectionToServer` is nil, you may need to hold `connectionToServer` via making it to be a property or retaining it.

Comment: This ain't a problem. See bold text above.

Comment: I saw you said that `annotsView` works fine. Does `annotsView` is a view and other thing may hold it? And nothing hold `connectionToServer`?

Comment: annotsView is not a view. Nothing holds these two. I mentioned above that everything about delegates works fine when using in my view controllers. Same code is used everywhere. Its just the case that calling custom delegate method in a class inherited from NSObject, with its custom delegate is not working.

Comment: That is to say u just make connectionToServer to use annotsView as a delegate and make annotsView to use connectionToServer as a delegate? This 2 object just weak hold each other, so i think if no one strongly hold connectionToServer, connectionToServer will become nil...

Answer (score 0):

You can check for solution here [Manage completion handler of NSURLSession from a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484548/manage-completion-handler-of-nsurlsession-from-a-custom-class/25486276#25486276)

Delegate explained.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
See My Example.


//
//  AppModel.swift
//  SampleProject
//
//  Created by on 21/09/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Foundation

@objc protocol AppmodelDelegate {

// define delegates
    optional func loginSuccess()
    optional func logOutSuccess()
    optional func loginFailed(error_message:String?)
    optional func propertyFetchingSuccess()

}

class AppModel: NSObject {

// class body.


//sharing instance to access

    final  class var sharedInstance : AppModel {
        struct Static {
            static var instance : AppModel?
        }
        if !(Static.instance != nil) {
            Static.instance = AppModel()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }


 }


Delegate call: eg. self.delegate?.propertyFetchingSuccess!()


Implementing in LoginViewController:


//
//  LoginViewController.swift
//  SampleProject
//
//  Created by on 21/09/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, AppmodelDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        AppModel.sharedInstance.delegate = self

}

    func propertyFetchingSuccess() {

println("propertyFetchingSuccess!!!")
    }
}
```