# NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest returns nil data

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsurlsession

I am new to Mac application development and our existing Mac application contains the following line of code

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResonse:response error:Error
```

A warning message getting displayed as

> sendSynchronousRequest is deprecated in macOS 10.11

and suggesting to use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:]

I have implemented the following code changes to use NSURLSession as suggested but it is returning the value of data as "nil". Can you please suggest what needs to be done in order to get the required data in response?

```
__block NSError *WSerror;
__block NSURLResponse *WSresponse;
__block NSData *myData;
NSURLSession *session =[NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    myData = data;
    WSresponse =response;
    WSerror = error;
}] resume];
 
NSString *theXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return theXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

The completion handler is asynchronous. You have to do your work **inside** the completion handler.

The `__block` declarations are pointless.

```
NSURLSession *session =[NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session  completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { 
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *theXml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // do something with `theXml`
    }
}] resume];
```

Comment: I need to return the value present in "theXml" but it is not allowing to use return statement inside it . If i place return outside the completionHandler then "return theXml" is being called first and it is a nil value  The code inside the completionHandler is never getting executed . Can you please suggest on how the value can be returned ?

Comment: It's impossible to return the value directly. The only way is to add a(nother) completion handler. And you have to call `dataTaskWithURL:completionHander` passing the `NSURL` rather than `session::completionHander`. Please learn to understand how asynchronous data processing works.

Comment: Do you say that the return at the end of the code is causing the code inside completionHandler not to execute? Can you please provide me a sample code on how to implement this case ?

Comment: No, you are using the wrong API. Here is an example with protocol/delegate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484548/manage-completion-handler-of-nsurlsession-from-a-custom-class